# How to hide my SmartDevice application on startup?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, smart-device

I made a `SmartDevice` application that runs on startup and I want it to be hidden at first launch.

I've tried `this.Hide()`, `this.Visible = false` and `ShowWindow(Handle, SW_HIDE)` in Form `Load()` event and `InitializeComponent()` with no luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you set the WindowState property of your main form?

Comment: there are only two options available, FormWindowState.Normal and FormWindowState.Maximized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CF automatically calls Show on the Form passed to Application.Run.  There is no avoiding that without avoiding the call to Application.Run.

The SDF has an Application2.Run that takes a parameter to tell it to not show the form.

You could do the same by creating your own message pump (though it's not a straightforward thing to do).

Answer (score 2):

declare two global vars :

```
int32 VGU_Left;
int32 VGU_Top;
```

in the on create of the form object :

```
VGU_Left=this.left;
VGU_Top=this.top;
this.left=this.width*-1;
this.top=this.height*-1;
```

and when you want to show the form :

```
if ((this.left<0)and(this.top<0)) then 
  this.left=VGU_Left;
  this.top=VGU_Top;
endif
```